# Is it possible to convert a MathProg MIP file to a format recognised by SCIP?

Tags: glpk, scip, mathprog

I've been using GLPK to solve some mixed integer programming problems. Here's a sample input file in MathProg format:

```
set REACTIONS;
set REACTANTS;
param Ys {i in REACTANTS, j in REACTIONS};
param Gamma {i in REACTANTS, j in REACTIONS};
param eps;
param delt;
var w {i in REACTANTS} >=-delt <=delt;
var R0 {i in REACTIONS} >=0 <=1, integer;
var Rn {i in REACTIONS} >=0 <=1, integer;
minimize z:  sum{i in REACTIONS} -Rn[i];
s.t. const1{i in REACTIONS} : sum{k in REACTANTS} w[k]*Gamma[k,i] <= delt*(1-R0[i]);
s.t. const2{i in REACTIONS} : -sum{k in REACTANTS} w[k]*Gamma[k,i] <= delt*(1-R0[i]);
s.t. const3{i in REACTIONS} : Rn[i] <= 1-R0[i];
s.t. const5{i in REACTIONS} : sum{k in REACTANTS} w[k]*Gamma[k,i] <= delt*(1-Rn[i])-eps;
s.t. const6{i in REACTIONS, j in REACTIONS: i <> j} : sum{k in REACTANTS} w[k]*(Ys[k,i]-Ys[k,j]) <= delt*(1-Rn[i]+Rn[j]+R0[j]);
data;
set REACTIONS:= 1 2 3 4 5 6;
set REACTANTS:= 1 2 3 4 5 6;
param Ys:   1   2   3   4   5   6:=
1    1  0   0   0   0   0
2    1  0   0   0   0   0
3    0  1   1   0   0   0
4    0  0   0   1   0   0
5    0  0   0   1   0   0
6    0  0   0   0   1   1;
param Gamma:    1   2   3   4   5   6:=
1    -1 1   0   0   0   1
2    -1 1   1   0   0   0
3    1  -1  -1  0   0   0
4    0  0   1   -1  1   0
5    0  0   0   -1  1   1
6    0  0   0   1   -1  -1;
param eps:=0.1;
param delt:=10;
end;
```

I've been running into performance problems for bigger problems of this type, and since SCIP claims to be several times faster than GLPK for MIP, it seems worth investigating. However, I haven't been able to make head or tail of the documentation when it comes to input file formats. [SCIP's homepage](http://scip.zib.de/#features) says that it supports AMPL format, and the GLPK's homepagesays that MathProg is a subset of AMPL. Trying to feed the above file into SCIP 3.1.0 via `scip -f file.nl` returns the following error:

```
read problem <file.nl>
============

no reader for input file <file.nl> available
```

I'm not sure whether this is because I've failed to build SCIP with AMPL support, or something else. I found [this blog post](http://zverovich.net/2012/08/07/using-scip-with-ampl.html) on building SCIP with AMPL support, but the instructions seem to be outdated as the source zip of SCIP 3.1.0 doesn't contain an `interfaces` folder.

So, I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to get SCIP to recognise my MathProg input as is?
2. If not, can anyone advise on how to convert it to a recognised format? An automated method would be preferable, as I don't really want to have to learn yet another format, but a manual method would be better than nothing.

Thanks for any help and apologies for my ignorance!

Comment: the tarball does have an `interfaces`-directory. It in located in the main SCIP-directory aka the SCIP-subdirectory of the SCIP Optimization Suite, if you downloaded the latter.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I managed to miss that! Unfortunately, scipampl didn't recognise the MathProg data as valid AMPL, so I presume that the relationship between MathProg and AMPL is more complicated than I'd hoped.

Comment: scipampl is an AMPL solver, so it accept input in .nl format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nl_(format)). I don't think MathProg supports that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I indicated in my comment above, the Ampl-interface is still included in the SCIP-distribution, and you should be able to compile it and read your problem 
as documented in the excellent blog post you cite.

If you feel tempted to try different file formats, I see two options for you:

1. use `glpk` for translating your problem into a [file format](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/group__FILEREADERS.php) that is recognizable by SCIP. I found methods `glp_write_mps()` and `glp_write_lp`. SCIP can read both `.lp` and `.mps`-files. Make sure that you use exactly these file extensions, because SCIP doesn't recognize files in `.lp`-format but ending with `.txt` instead.
2. Use `Zimpl` to formulate your problems instead. The two formats of `Zimpl` and `Ampl` are strikingly similar, see the [documentation](http://zimpl.zib.de/download/zimpl.pdf) for examples and further reference. Problem descriptions in `Zimpl` can be translated into `.lp`-format or read directly by SCIP, if you compile SCIP with the `ZIMPL=true`-option, which is the default.

Comment: Marking as accepted as this was useful information, although it didn't quite get me to a solution. One of colleagues found the answer I was looking for: `glpsol` includes an option to convert MathProg to .lp format, which is accepted by SCIP. In case it's useful to anyone else, here's how:  
    ``glpsol --check --wlp newfilename.lp --math oldfilename.glpk``

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. I am not that used to glpk, when I downloaded it to answer your question, I thought the only access would be to include the library into own projects, which I figured you must have already written. I didn't quite understand that there is a standalone-executable `glpsol`, neither did the manual give me a hint about that.